# Adjust HttpRequst Timeout Before Creating any HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, timeout, httpwebrequest, telegram, telegram-bot

In C# 5 and winform, I used a library created by Telegram Company. In this library there is a function `SendDocument(UserId,DocumentStream)`. I know in this function, they used some `HttpWebRequest`, and the `Timeout` property of that is not handled. because sometimes it can't send large documents and after exact 100 seconds(default timeout in DotNet), the function throws an exception `The task was canceled`.

From the document of Telegram Company, we can send 50 MB files and my example files is about 15 MB.

Ok, Now I want to adjust the timeout of all `HttpWebRequest` of my server but I don't have any feature for this.

Can I adjust all `HttpWebRequest.Timeout` property in my server??

Answer (score 2):

This is not directly related to your question, but may help ease your mind.

My advice is, **don't bother adjusting the timeout**. It is not likely to help. Here is what I have gone through:

I have tried to upload a 20M mp4 video file using Telegram Bot API. From a Raspberry Pi, it took 5 minutes, then returned a 504 Gateway-Timeout error. From a hosted server, it took 1 minute, then returned a 504 Gateway-Timeout error. In both cases, however, the video did eventually reach the recipient 5 minutes later. So, the upload seemed somewhat successful, yet not quite successful.

I tried to fix the problem by streaming the upload. Same problem persisted.

I tried to adjust the HTTP timeout parameter. Same problem persisted.

I tried to use cURL to make the request (instead of using [telepot](https://github.com/nickoala/telepot), a Python library I author). Same problem persisted.

I suspect the problem lies with the Telegram servers, so I talked to Bot Support. They got back to me once, saying they have made some improvements and asked if I still have the same problem. But same problem still persists.

So, it seems the problem does lie with the Telegram servers. It's not your code.

Comment: It means they did it with purpose? Weak API.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's a pretty old question but may be my answer will help somebody. When I tried to send cosiderably large files via my bot I received `Telegram.Bot.Exceptions.ApiRequestException: Request timed out` and the only solution I found was [this](https://github.com/TelegramBots/telegram.bot/issues/305) issue. Which wasn't really helpfull because if you check source code then you'll see that passing cancellation token does nothing with request timeout. But then I saw that you can pass HttpClient to your bot client instance and make it something like this:

```
        _httpClient = new HttpClient();
        _httpClient.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0); // 5 min
        _client = new TelegramBotClient(botConfig.Token, _httpClient);
```

Hope this will help